# MySQL data consistency: multiple users buy the same product at the same time

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc

I'm developing a website that enables users to buy products online. I got following code:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void buy(Integer itemId) {
        int amount = queryItemAmount(itemId); #1 // issue SELECT query

        if (amount > 0) { #2
            buy(itemId); // #3 issue UPDATE query, decrease the amount of this product
        }
    }
```

I'm worrying about `buy()` method will be invoked if the amount of the product reaches to zero.

For example, 2 users are buying the same product at the same time. User A just finished executing #1 and has got 1 for the amount of this product, so he will continue to execute #2. But before he executes #3, user B just finished executing #1 and got 1 for the amount of this product, too(Because User A hasn't executed #3 so the amount of product doesn't decrease). If this happens, user B will buy the product zero that shouldn't exist.

How to solve this problem?
I'm using SpringMVC-4.1.5 and MySQL-5.5

Comment: Put this logic into the database, best on a before insert trigger. Or you create a procedure to do it.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Procedure can do this well. But my database will be in cluster and tables will be in different machines so I'm unable to use procedure

Comment: @JorgeCampos I want a none-database way to solve this..

Comment: Why not? The clustering will not be a problem for a procedure/function (since mysql does not support procedures). The clustering will be managed by the RDBMs itself your application layer does not have to care about that

Comment: @JorgeCampos Ok, I'll try. But is there any none-database way to solve this?

Comment: Well you can use a little trick. on the buy method your insert query would be something like: `insert into buy select :itemId from items where itemId = :itemId and amount>0` an insert select checking if the item is avaiable at the insert command. then you check whether the insert returns the amount of inserted lines, if 0 you return this info to the app. And don't forget to put this on a transaction, if the insert happens you update the amount

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sounds good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO the correct way would be using a single transaction, which would do the following in the process:

- lock the appropriate rows in the DB, so other transactions can't modify it,
- check if there is enough from the product (if not, warn the user and rollback)
- let the user checkout the product
- commit and release the lock